# MessageBox not showing on event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, messagebox

I have a program in which I show a (System.Windows) MessageBox on an event but it doesn't show up. Please notice that I am pretty sure that this worked on a previous update of VS2019 but not on Version 16.11.5 and on VS2022RC.

[image]

I have also searched for some hints but nothing came out. So either I did some blatant mistake or this is something new.

I don't think I can provide any other additional information for I think that this might be misleading.

Thanks for helping
Patrick

Comment: Is your callback executing on the main thread? Also, I highly recommend to never use any overload of `MessageBox.Show` that does not take a parent window, because the popup may easily show up behind any other windows (Add `this` as first argument)

Comment: Oh wow that solved the problem! Thanks so have I got change a million MessageBox  call in my program?! I think the answer is yes... In any case the messagebox was not showing up behind it really was not showing at all! You might want to post it as an answer to close the question.

Comment: Messagebox may seem convenient but it's rarely a good plan in real world production code. I've recently seen live code reported any error in a messagebox. Called from inside a loop processing many records. Made the app totally unusable. You couldn't close the app down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show(string)` and any of it's overloads that do not take a `IWin32Window` create a non-modal window. This message box then may show up behind other windows or eventually not at all (not sure why the later, but maybe it's outside the screen or so). To prevent that, always use an overload with `IWin32Window` as first argument. In a simple WinForms app, this is typically the form calling the `Show()` method, so the argument can just be `this`.

**TL;DR**

Change

```
MessageBox.Show("Message");
```

to

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "Message");
```